# Fibonnaci in F#

Tags: f#

with the multiple assignment (ie a,b=b,a) in f# its possible to write Fibonacci in a single line .. Can some one show how it is .. i know its possible in ruby

Comment: From how the question is phrased this might be more approprite in code-golf: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott Hanselman pretty much covers this in [this blog post.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode13FibonacciEdition.aspx)

Here is the relevant snippet:

```
let rec fib n = if n < 2 then 1 else fib (n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

Scott got that from [Dustin Cambell's blog.](http://diditwith.net/2007/02/08/FibonacciNumbersCachingAndClosures.aspx)  I post Scott's version because he also has the Ruby code for it.  It's worth noting that in F#, variables are generally immutable so `a,b = b,a` is not actually reassigning anything (I don't think it's even valid syntax).  Rather, a function like `let swap (a,b) = (b,a)` is taking a tuple and returning a new tuple with the contents reversed.

Comment: And incorrect for n=0 too as pointed out in the comments on Hanselman's blog.

Answer (score 4):

Longer but much faster version (via tail recursion in auxiliary function `fibi`):

```
let fib = let rec fibi a b = function | 0 -> a | c -> fibi b (a+b) (c-1) in fibi 0I 1I
```

Answer (score 3):

For the uninitiated, Seq.unfold is a sequence generator. It accepts as seed as input and invokes a function which returns the next element in the sequence as `Some(nextElement, nextSeed)`, or `None` to terminates the sequence.

It makes for a very interesting fibonacci one-liner:

```
> let fibs = (0L, 1L) |> Seq.unfold (fun (a, b) -> Some(a, (b, a+b)));;

val fibs : seq<int64>

> fibs |> Seq.take 50 |> Seq.toList;;
val it : int64 list =
  [0L; 1L; 1L; 2L; 3L; 5L; 8L; 13L; 21L; 34L; 55L; 89L; 144L; 233L; 377L; 610L;
   987L; 1597L; 2584L; 4181L; 6765L; 10946L; 17711L; 28657L; 46368L; 75025L;
   121393L; 196418L; 317811L; 514229L; 832040L; 1346269L; 2178309L; 3524578L;
   5702887L; 9227465L; 14930352L; 24157817L; 39088169L; 63245986L; 102334155L;
   165580141L; 267914296L; 433494437L; 701408733L; 1134903170L; 1836311903L;
   2971215073L; 4807526976L; 7778742049L]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let main = System.Console.WriteLine("Fibonacci")
```

Comment: I think he/she means the definition of a fibonacci function ^^;

Comment: Well, it still writes Fibonacci in a single line :)

Comment: Are you really joking? The asker really asked clear question.

Comment: Clearly there is no place for humor on SO >_>

Comment: @eriawan: lets say i just prefer simple solutions. clear question, clear answer.